# I have a 98 neon that won't start

Tags: dodge, starter, neon

I have a 98dodge neon, and all the electrical works but my starter will not even click, nothing else is a problem only the starter I've checked all the connections and break pedal and gearshift it's an automatic they all seem good and tight  what else could be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Take the starter off, take it down to your nearest AutoZone/O'Reilly's/Checker/etc. auto parts store and have them bench check it for you. I'll bet your solenoid is no longer functioning, and therefor your starter has quit working.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting any clicking from the starter, that means the solenoid is not engaging. 99% chance that it is the starter. Remove the starter and take it for a test to any local shop. Make sure it produces at least 60 amps of current or it will not turn your engine over.

More help available [here](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/the-car-wont-start-not-even-click-but-everything-else-works-fine-in-the-car)